# Condition number for matrix of eigenvectors of a diagonally dominant matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition

Let $A$ be a diagonalizable matrix, i.e., $A=X D X^{-1}$. Recall that columns of $X$ correspond to eigenvectors of $A$, and the diagonal entries of the diagonal matrix $D$ correspond to its eigenvalues.

Suppose that $A$ is strictly row/column dominant. In particular assume that $A_{ii}\geq \sum_{j\neq i} |A_{ij}| + c$ for some $c>0$. Similarly for the column sums.

Is it possible to choose $X$ such that  the condition number of $X$ is bounded, i.e., can we choose $X$ such that  $\kappa(X)= \|X\|_2 \times \|X^{-1}\|_2$ is bounded (e.g., in terms of $c$)?

Comment: Recall that the eigenvectors corresponding to distinct eigenvalues are orthogonal to each other and that in situations where there are repeated eigenvalues you *can* select the eigenvectors so that they're orthogonal.  In those situations, the condition number of $X$ is 1.  However, you can also choose the eigenvectors stupidly.  Let $D=I$ and let $X$ be a very badly conditioned matrix.  What happens then?

Comment: Good point! I guess for my purposes the question is whether it is always possible to choose X such that $\kappa(X)$ is small.  I'll update the question accordingly. 

By the way, I'm not assuming that the matrix is symmetric. So, it is not always possible to choose an orthogonal vectors.

Comment: @BrianBorchers Why should the eigenvectors be orthogonal? There's nothing about $A$ being normal, real symmetric, complex Hermitian, etc. The only assumption here is that $A$ is diagonalizable.

Comment: Are you willing to allow for arbitrary scaling of the columns of $X$, or should the columns of $X$ be normalized so that each eigenvector has norm 1?

Comment: Does the result depend on whether the scalings are allowed? If so, suppose that we allow them.

Comment: Yesyou'll at least need the flexibility to arbitrarily scale columns of $X$.  I've constructed a 3x3 example where $\kappa(X)> 1 \times 10^{20}$ and $A$ is diagonally dominate by a large margin.  It's not hard to do this by picking the eigenvectors to make $X$ very badly conditioned and adjusting the the distinct eigenvalues as needed to make $A$ diagonally dominant.

Comment: @BrianBorchers This sounds interesting. I see how you can go from starting with a well-behaved $X$ to another matrix $X'$ that is ill-conditioned by scaling the columns arbitrarily (e.g., by multiplying some columns by $\epsilon$). The converse is less clear to me: Is it always the case that I can write $A=XDX^{-1}$ with $X$ that is not ill-conditioned? That is starting with an ill-conditioned (yet invertible) $X$ can we always construct a well-behaved $X$?

Comment: @Ozzy my intuition tells me that scaling columns alone isn't going to be sufficient- scaling procedures that scale rows and columns are often but not always effective and I'd suspect that column scaling alone would be less effective.  However, I don't have any particular examples.

Comment: @BrianBorchers Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, take for $\epsilon>0$ small:
$$ \left(\begin{matrix} 1 & \epsilon \\ 0 & 1 + \epsilon^2 \end{matrix}\right)$$
Eigenvalues $1$ and $1+\epsilon^2$ corresponds to eigenvectors 
$$ \left(\begin{matrix} 1  \\ 0 \end{matrix}\right) \; \;  \mbox{and} \; \; \left(\begin{matrix} 1/\epsilon \\ 1  \end{matrix}\right),$$
respectively. The matrix $X$ has, up to a global scaling (irrelevant for the condition number), the form :
 $$ X = \left(\begin{matrix} 1 & t/\epsilon \\ 0 & t \end{matrix}\right)$$
for some  $t\neq 0$ and then
 $$ X^{-1} = \left(\begin{matrix} 1 & -1/\epsilon \\ 0 & 1/t \end{matrix}\right)$$
Calculating lower bounds for the eigenvalues of $X^* X$ and $(X^{-1})^* X^{-1}$ and simplifying we see that the condition number is bounded from below by:
$$ C \geq \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{1}{t}+t + \frac{t}{\epsilon^2}\right) $$
which has a minimum for $t=\epsilon$. We conclude that $ C(X)\geq \frac{1}{\epsilon} + \frac{\epsilon}2$ whatever choice you make for the diagonalizing matrix $X$.